# A single word describing something that needs attention

Tags: single-word-requests

After a work is peer reviewed, it moves into a state in which the author of the work must review critiques and answer questions from the peer who reviewed the work.

What would be an appropriate word to describe the state the work is in?

E.g., in a state trail:

> Completed → Reviewing → _____ → Fixing → Accepted

Comment: "Returned" "Responding"

Comment: I'd call it the *feedback* phase.

Comment: The work is in limbo?  As in Dictionary.com's definition, "3.
an intermediate, transitional, or midway state or place."

Comment: Is this a question on scientific peer review? Or simply the copyedited and typeset stage before galley proofs?

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, do you know how it is possible to receive a -1 score in this part of the comment section?  Seems odd as I do not see the mechanics for this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This phase of the publishing process is usually called *revision* or *revise and resubmit (R&R)*.
http://www.emeraldgrouppublishing.com/authors/guides/promote/review.htm

https://www.soc.umn.edu/~uggen/PeerReview.pdf

Some publishers use a more interactive process that gives authors the opportunity to make corrections, respond to reviewers, and then make final revisions before publication.

http://www.biogeosciences.net/review/review_process_and_interactive_public_discussion.html

Comment: I assumed his "fixing" stage to be the revision stage. I submitted this answer initially before I saw "fixing".

Comment: @ Medica Asking questions properly is often at least as hard as answering them.

Answer (score 2):

You should have no qualms using *triage* as to mean a stage of treatment to your work to

- first, sort and prioritize questions to be addressed
- then, sort and prioritize your resources to address the questions and issues raised

> [tri·age](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/triage)  (trē-äzh′, trē′äzh′)
>   n.
>
> 1. A process for sorting injured people into groups based on their need for or likely benefit from immediate medical treatment. Triage is used in hospital emergency rooms, on battlefields, and at disaster sites when limited medical resources must be allocated.
> 2. A system used to allocate a scarce commodity, such as food, only to those capable of deriving the greatest benefit from it.
> 3. A process in which things are ranked in terms of importance or priority: "For millions of Americans, each week becomes a stressful triage between work and home that leaves them feeling guilty, exhausted and angry" (Jill Smolowe).
>
> tr.v. tri·aged, tri·ag·ing, tri·ag·es
>   To sort or allocate by triage: triaged the patients according to their symptoms.
>   [French, from trier, to sort, from Old French.]
>
> *The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fourth Edition copyright ©2000 by Houghton Mifflin Company. Updated in 2009. Published by Houghton Mifflin Company. All rights reserved.*

The word ***triage***, borrowed into English, has so far been mostly to mean to sort issues to be prioritized for attention

- hospital usage: sort patients by priorities for medical attention
- software issues triage: sort issues by priorities for mitigation
- [computer software usage and deployment triage](http://dpadvantage.wordpress.com/2010/05/07/computer-software-triage/).
- [administrative triage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Triage): sort issues and request for priorities of attention

Most of the material you read on [software engineering triage](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Bug_management/How_to_triage) is written on defect/bug management.  Software engineering has begun to use the term *issues* as a more general term over *bugs*: Google search for [Issues vs Bugs](https://www.google.com/#q=issues+vs+bugs). Where software issues could be bugs/defects,  attention-required, enhancement, clarification-required, etc.

Most software defect triage systems have been recycled to be used for triage of issues, regardless that the names of those systems had been grandfathered as "bug management systems".

The steps in software issues triage is similar to the literary work triage you have:

Issue (request to create a new software)
  -> planning
 -> triage to prioritize resources
 -> create software
 -> completed software
 -> reviewing
 -> triage of issues discovered during review
 -> fixing
 -> Acceptance/rejection (if rejection, back to triage).